# Checking if a str is in a list of str?

Tags: python, string, list

```
['aa', 'ab', 'aaaa', 'ggg', 'agaga', 'a']
```

From the above list, I'd like to be able to find out if the list contains a 'b' in the shortest possible ways. Thanks!

Comment: Your expected outcome being "no" (even though `ab` has the substring `b`)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For substrings:

```
any('b' in s for s in input_list)
```

For full strings:

```
'b' in input_list
```

Answer (score 1):

You can join the items an test for a b in the joined string:

```
'b' in ' '.join(your_list)
```

Comment: This works well enough if you're checking for a string of length one. But if you're looking for `"xyz"`, and `your_list` contains `['ax', 'yz']`, your expression returns True even though no single element of `your_list` contains "xyz"

Comment: Then make the separator a space.

Comment: Then it will incorrectly give True if you're looking for `"x yz"`.